# My custom font is not working

Tags: css, fonts

I have tried

```
@font-face {
font-family: Jua;
src: url('/fonts/jua.ttf');
}
@font-face {
font-family: Jua;
src: url('..../fonts/jua.ttf');
}
@font-face {
font-family: Jua;
src: url('.../fonts/jua.ttf');
}
```

Im trying to change my body text with.

```
body,
button,
input,
select,
optgroup,
textarea {
color: #d6d6d6;
font-family: Jua !important;
font-size: 16px;
font-size: 1rem;
line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Also tried puting the fonts in my theme root directory, Cleared cache

Comment: tell us what is a directory tree in your project, where is style.css and where is font.ttf? please show your files tree

Comment: Updateed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of this you could do.

Check your fonts loads in the browser.

[image]

I only see above. So, maybe check your directory permission.
And then check your CSS font path. 
Try to add absolute path and check. Then do the path modification.

Comment: What permission  do i need? My font folder is 777 and font is 777

Comment: Can you direct access to the folder? please send your directory path.

Answer (score 0):

In your case your `src` attribute for `@font-face` should have value `url('fonts/jua.ttf')` because font file is in directory, which is on the same level as stylesheet file.